# Merging duplicate elements within an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I currently have an `IEnumerable<MyObject>` where `MyObject` has the properties `String Name` and `long Value`.

If i was to have within the Enumerable, 10 instances of `MyObject`, each with a different name and value, with the exception of one having the same name as the other.

Does .NET (or LINQ) have a built in method which will allow me to find the duplicate, and if possible, merge the `Value` property so that there ends up being only 9 elements within the enumerable, each with a distinct `Name` and the one that had a duplicate has the `Value` that is equal to the sum of its self and the duplicate.

So far i have found that the only way to iterate over the entire `IEnumerable` and look for the duplicates and generate a new `IEnumerable` of unique items, but this seems untidy and slow.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can group items by name and project results to 'merged' objects:

```
objects.GroupBy(o => o.Name)
       .Select(g => new MyObject { Name = g.Key, Value = g.Sum(o => o.Value) });
```

UPDATE: Another option, if new MyObject instantiation is undesired (e.g. you have many properties in this class, or you should preserver references) then you can use aggregation with first item in group as accumulator:

```
objects.GroupBy(o => o.Name)
       .Select(g => g.Skip(1).Aggregate(
                        g.First(), (a, o) => { a.Value += o.Value; return a; }));
```

Comment: It's worth noting that one should probably specify the type of `StringComparer` to use :)

Comment: Yet another variant `var dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>(); Parallel.ForEach(objects, obj => dict.AddOrUpdate(obj.Name, obj.Value, (key, oldvalue) => oldvalue + obj.Value));`

Answer (score 8):

```
list.GroupBy(e => e.Name).Select(group => new MyObject
    {
        Name = group.Key,
        Value = group.Sum(e => e.Value)
    }
)
```

**Update:**
*Another variant:*

```
list.GroupBy(
    e => e.Name,
    e => e,
    (name, group) => group.Aggregate((result, e) =>
        {
            result.Value += e.Value;
            return result;
        }
    )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I dont know a single method solution but what about:

```
set.GroupBy(g=>g.Name).Select(g=> new MyObject{Name=g.Key, Value=g.Sum(i=>i.Value)});
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement interface IEquatable and use Ditinct method. As follow:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var items = new List<MyClass>
                    {
                        new MyClass
                        {
                            Name = "Name1",
                            Value = 50
                        },
                        new MyClass
                        {
                            Name = "Name2",
                            Value = 20
                        },
                        new MyClass
                        {
                            Name = "Name3",
                            Value = 50
                        }
                    };
        var distinct = items.Distinct().ToList();
    }
}

internal class MyClass : **IEquatable<MyClass>**
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    **public bool Equals(MyClass other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
            return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            return true;
        return this.Value == other.Value;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
            return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType())
            return false;
        return this.Equals((MyClass)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Value;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(MyClass left, MyClass right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(MyClass left, MyClass right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }**
}
```

Comment: This does not satisfy the requirement that the values of entries with identical names are summed in the result.